# signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) android::nativePrepareStatement(_JNIEnv, _jclass, long long, _jstring*)

Tags: android, crash, google-play, android-sqlite, backtrace

I am getting signal 11. but I cannot reproduce myself. Google Play has reported a large number of the following crash.
I totally don't understand what the reason behind it. I'm using Mapbox in sense of native code
But I think maybe it occurs for using sqlite db. but dont know why its happening.

```
 backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000000d1afc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::nativePrepareStatement(_JNIEnv, _jclass, long long, _jstring*)+60)
  #00  pc 00000000002dfc83  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+130)
  #00  pc 000000000053cd13  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement+146)
  #00  pc 0000000000541f77  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare+142)
  #00  pc 0000000000468f8f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare+190)
  #00  pc 0000000000546e11  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>+368)
  #00  pc 000000000054443f  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement+102)
  #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #00  pc 000000000042e0e7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250)
  #00  pc 00000000000dffb7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+174)
  #00  pc 0000000000210691  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread, art::ArtMethod, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280)
  #00  pc 000000000020bfd3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod, art::Thread, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+774)
  #00  pc 00000000004233b9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+556)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 00000000003b9c26  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.isDatabaseIntegrityOk+222)
  #00  pc 0000000000423609  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1148)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 00000000003ae840  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.database.DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.diagnoseDatabase+128)
  #00  pc 0000000000425479  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+980)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2914  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20)
  #00  pc 00000000003af0c4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.database.DefaultDatabaseErrorHandler.onCorruption+304)
  #00  pc 0000000000424aa9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1432)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #00  pc 00000000003bbf44  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.onCorruption+80)
  #00  pc 00000000001ebf0d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.65484028430099480)+192)
  #00  pc 00000000001f06f1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+124)
  #00  pc 0000000000417c59  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+808)
  #00  pc 00000000000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #00  pc 0000000000542df5  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction+276)
  #00  pc 000000000054432d  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction+44)
  #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #00  pc 000000000042e0e7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250)
  #00  pc 00000000000dffb7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread, unsigned int, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+174)
  #00  pc 0000000000210691  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread, art::ArtMethod, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+280)
  #00  pc 000000000020bfd3  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod, art::Thread, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+774)
  #00  pc 00000000004233b9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+556)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 00000000000218f2  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000005f/MeasurementDynamite.apk (ik.r+90)
  #00  pc 0000000000423609  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1148)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 000000000002e368  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000005f/MeasurementDynamite.apk (ma.K+72)
  #00  pc 0000000000423609  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1148)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2814  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20)
  #00  pc 000000000002c992  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000005f/MeasurementDynamite.apk (lp.run+78)
  #00  pc 0000000000424aa9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (MterpInvokeInterface+1432)
  #00  pc 00000000000d2a14  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_interface+20)
  #00  pc 000000000002e2b2  /data/user_de/0/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000005f/MeasurementDynamite.apk (ma.C+18)
  #00  pc 00000000001ebf0d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.65484028430099480)+192)
  #00  pc 00000000001f06f1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::interpreter::EnterInterpreterFromEntryPoint(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*)+124)
  #00  pc 0000000000417c59  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+808)
  #00  pc 00000000000dc5a1  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+32)
  #00  pc 000000000205942f  /memfd:/jit-cache (kn.T+6254)
  #00  pc 00000000000d7bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68)
  #00  pc 000000000042e0e7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250)
```

Comment: we used to get these a lot 2 years back, for us it was due to some bug in google ads and chrome webview-trichrome syncing or something so we had to update it latest version which solved it, this error occurs randomly when some users click on any full page interstitial advertisements, I am not sure what caused the issue in your case but check if all dependencies are up to date

Comment: At a guess, it could be that the database is being corrupted and if the default handler is invoked then SQLiteOpenHelper will kindly (or not) create a new database which may then result in the prepare statement failing (possibly due to table not found as  the database would in such a scenario not have any of the expected tables).

Comment: in some stack traces we used to see the word `ad dynamite` which confirms that its from google ads